# Angular JS: How to set same URL to all navigation in page?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to set default URL for all my page in my web(eg. www.bola.com), so user will only see this URL for the entire time. And if user refresh the page, it will be back to default homepage. (I'm using Angular Js + Ionic Framework)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead of ng-rote and not assigning urls to your states.

Then use `<a ui-sref="some.state">Click</a>`, to change state and the url field is not updated.

Comment: Yes, this would be the best way, just a heads up that you would need to set the url of each state as the the same thing, or to null, and use the `$state` names for navigation.